# Package "must match -any, but the stack configuration has no specified version" on github dependency

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

Getting this error on my repository where I tried to use a dependency from GitHub:

```
$ stack build

Error: While constructing the build plan, the following exceptions were encountered:

In the dependencies for quickcheck-fail-0.1.0.0:
    ifctx must match -any, but the stack configuration has no specified version
needed since quickcheck-fail is a build target.

Some potential ways to resolve this:

  * Set 'allow-newer: true' to ignore all version constraints and build anyway.

  * You may also want to try using the 'stack solver' command.

Plan construction failed.
```

I'm out of ideas what exactly is wrong here. Please see the repo to reproduce: https://github.com/k-bx/quickcheck-fail

Comment: I have deleted my answer (I didn't notice that you already had the `extra-deps` entry, and `git@` vs. `https:` for the GitHub link should make no difference, as you noted). It is a strange error indeed.

Comment: Please include all relevant code here, rather than just a link to the repo on github.

Comment: It appears to be a typo: you have `ifctx` rather than `ifcxt` in `package.yaml`/the `.cabal` file. (It's an easy typo to make: I did the same thing the first few times I tried hoogling it, and even so it took me a while to notice it in the files :))

Comment: @duplode thank you! That thing was driving me nuts :)

Answer (score 2):

The correct answer was provided by @duplode in the comment.

> It appears to be a typo: you have ifctx rather than ifcxt in package.yaml/the .cabal file. (It's an easy typo to make: I did the same thing the first few times I tried hoogling it, and even so it took me a while to notice it in the files :)) – duplode 3 hours ago